# How can I generate a Random Number that does not change in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I am generating a chart with random data:

```
Date        Value
1/1/2018    123
1/2/2018    453
```

I used `RAND` to generate the values, but don't want them to recalculate all the time. How to suppress the recalculation of `RAND`?

Answer (score 6):

If you are happy with your generated data, you can replace your formulae with the values that were generated.

1. Mark your area
2. Copy
3. Right click -> "Paste special" -> "Paste values only"

The formulae will now have been replaced by the values.
You can also paste with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

---

Thanks to Jamie Evans for the copy/paste suggestion. My solution skips pasting into notepad. I would have just left a comment if I had >=50 points.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "You can't" (at least not without script). However, unless your work is scientific in nature, you probably don't need "random" numbers, just *unpredictable* ones. (In fact, to be technical, even RAND doesn't generate *true* random numbers; rather, it uses a complex algorithm to ... well, generate an *unpredictable* number.)

The problem, as you know, is that RAND recalculates. But we can write any number of formulas that will produce "pseudo-random" numbers from the date. For instance, assuming that your dates are in Column A and your "random numbers" in Column B, you could put something like this in B2 and copy down as far as needed:

`=VALUE(TEXT(INT(((A2*COS(DAY(A2))*PI())-INT(A2*COS(DAY(A2))*PI()))*1000)+IF(INT(((A2*COS(DAY(A2))*PI())-INT(A2*COS(DAY(A2))*PI()))*1000)<100,WEEKDAY(A2)*100,0),"000"))`

This will use features of the date to generate a "pseudo-random" 3-digit number.

The overly-complicated formula isn't all that important. I just smashed some math functions together. They could have been endless combinations of others.

However, if you just need a "unique and non-repeating" number—for instance, as a trigger for a platform like Zapier—all you really need is the numeric format of the date itself:

`=VALUE(A2)`

...copied down as needed.

Either formula can work as an array formula (i.e., placed in one cell and filling the entire column) with minor changes:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A = "", "", VALUE(TEXT(INT(((A2:A*COS(DAY(A2:A))*PI())-INT(A2:A*COS(DAY(A2:A))*PI()))*1000)+IF(INT(((A2:A*COS(DAY(A2:A))*PI())-INT(A2:A*COS(DAY(A2:A))*PI()))*1000)<100,WEEKDAY(A2:A)*100,0),"000")))`

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A = "", "", VALUE(A2:A))`

Answer (score 1):

With a google script

tools > script editor

Then make a function. 
You will need to hook the function up to a button or some other event.

In order to enter the number you need to make select a range. Then put the value in with and array of arrays. Think of it like an array of rows.

Here is my sample Google script

```
function generateNumbers () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var randNumberRows = []

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var row = []
    row.push(randInt(-20,20));
    row.push(randInt(-20,20));
    row.push(randInt(-20,20));
    randNumberRows.push(row);
  }  

  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:C21");
  range.setValues(randNumberRows);
}

function randInt(start, end) {
  // range is from start to end + 1 so it is inclusive
  r = end - start + 1
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * r) + start;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a very simple easy solution, two easy little workarounds:

- With Excel as well:
  Generate as many random numbers as you want in Excel, copy paste, done
- Notepad:
  Generate in Google Sheets, copy paste into notepad, then copy paste back in, done

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Google PowerTools sheet plugin](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/power_tools/1058867473888) to [place random numbers in the range](https://www.ablebits.com/docs/google-sheets-generate-values/) you have selected and they will not change.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into the same question tonight and found this paper: https://www.ssl.berkeley.edu/~mlampton/RandomSpreadsheet4.pdf

You can use the formulas in that document to create your own pseudo-random number generator in a few minutes. That will give you a list of random numbers that will only change when you change the seed.